# How to display an phylogenetic tree structure in WPF

Tags: wpf, phylogeny

I am a newbie to WPF. The question is about displaying a tree structure in WPF.

I have a WPF app, which will connect to a remote database. One table (Taxonomy table) in the DB has two columns: "Parent node" (varchar(50)), and "Child node"(varchar(50)). Now I want to display that phylogenetic tree (as shown in the pic). Each nodes on the tree is coupled with a checkBox, and therefore, the user is able to select multiple nodes as they need.

Due to lack of knowledge in WPF, I really have no idea how to achieve that. What controls (or combination of controls) should be used here? Is WCF necessary in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Any suggestion or tutorial is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You'll need a `TreeView` and a way to retrieve the data from database.

Comment: @Joulukuusi: Thanks. Current I just remote access the DB. I am not sure if adding WCF will improve the performance.

Comment: Is the current performance inacceptable? If so, you'd better create another question about database access. There's a small into to `TreeView` control that you may want to read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Comment: @Joulukuusi: Great. Thanks for the tutorial, I will look into it.